# Local WiFi Network very slow even though the WiFi Link Speed is 433 Mbps

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-router

So I have this problem in my laptops in the network. Both Laptops support Dualband AC and has a link speed of 433 Mbps for both laptops. My main WiFi extender is capable of 1.7Gbps wirelessly(rated speed) and is connected directly with a CAT 7 (10 Gigabit) LAN cable to the main routers gigabit port.

But for some reason, my local network speeds is capped at max of 100mbps when speed testing it and even just copying files over the network. THis is even though the slowest device in the network is rated 433mbps which is the laptops. How do I make the laptops use the full 433mbps bandwidth?.

[image]
[image]

I Also already set the Channel Width to 80hz. still the same.:/
[image]

Also, I get over 200mbits over the Internet via my 5Ghz WiFi, hence I expect at least 200 mbits over the local network. :/

Just look below, my internet averagee 120-130mbps, but local network only gets around 80-90mbps. :/
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The speed shown in the Wi-Fi Status window isn't the real speed of your WiFi connection. WiFi can be disturbed by walls, water, people and so on. So the speed will always be lower than the advertised speed.

The real speed you're going to get depends on your setup. Do you have other APs in your area? If there are any walls between your AP and your PC the thickness and the material used also influences speed. Any other electrical installation such as lights, microwaves, fridges may also influence your WiFi.

Comment: There are no other WiFi interferance in the house as we are in a new subdivision and no neighbors yet. There is no obstacle as the laptops are meter away from the router connected to the 5Ghz network. Now I was expecting at least 200mbps in local network speeds given this circumstance as I know about half of it goes to other things it has to do wirelessly. So really,is 100mbits wirelessly is normal?. Cuz I'm getting well over 200mbits when accessing the internet wirelessly, so I expect my local network to be at least 200mbits fast. :/

Comment: In my setup my router is about 50cm away from my phone, on 5GHz I get about 300-500mbit/s on 5GHz and 100-150mbit/s on 2.4GHz. So I'd say your 100mbit/s are normal. My link to 5GHz is advertised as 866mbit/s and on 2.4GHz it's 433mbit/s as well.

Comment: Still underwhelming really, cuz I was testing the local network speed vs internet speed, and the average difference is speeds is around 40-50 mbps, where the internet is actually much faster than my local network. I added a screenshot of the average local network speed and internet speed. :/

Comment: Well if you really want to get the full speed with maximum stability you will have to use a wired connection.