# Low file transfer speed in local WiFi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a Speedster KN-3010 router and 2 modern laptops. There was a task to send files from one laptop to another via SMB in Windows. And the speed is higher than 100 megabits and does not rise! If I just download from a torrent, then 500 megabits freely pulls on both laptops, and between them 100 and the ceiling! I tried to create a torrent instead of SMB and transfer it between laptops, P2P. But everything is unchanged - it does not rise above 100 megabits at all. What could it be and how to get back to normal speed?

Comment: Are both laptops on 5GHz? Are you using 80MHz-wide channels? Are both laptops capable of at least 2x2 802.11ac ("AC1200")? Are you on a clean 80MHz-wide channel? With AC1200-class equipment, you should be able to get close to 300Mbps wireless-to-wireless under good radio conditions. SMB can be a bit inefficient and would lower that some more, but I would expect you could get 200Mbps of SMB3.x wireless-to-wireless over AC1200-class equipment.

Comment: Both laptops can download data from Internet up to 500Mbps without any problem. So, hardware completely support this speed. Radio conditions are perfect - 5 meters between laptops and 5 meters to router with no walls.

Comment: Are you sure that both the measurements are correct? windows SMB transfers usually display speeds in Megabytes (MB) rather than Megabits (Mb). 100 M**B**/s happens to be the max speed of 802.11n wireless. Try out using iperf between your machines, and see if the speeds are any different

Comment: Why only SMB? I've checked to transfer files using P2P either. But P2P speed was also not higher 100Mbps

Comment: This guy had a similar problem. https://superuser.com/questions/1589091/local-wifi-network-very-slow-even-though-the-wifi-link-speed-is-433-mbps?rq=1
And he got no solution too.